# Setting Variable to readlines() index

Tags: python, variables, txt

I am simply opening a `.txt` and trying to set the first line to the variable `x`. My print function works just fine, but when I set it to a variable, all hell breaks loose. Am I missing something?

**My .txt**

```
cat
dog
horse
brid
```

**Code**

```
txt = open('C:/Users/z/OneDrive/Desktop/New_Text_Doc.txt', 'r')
print(txt.readlines(0)[0])
x = txt.readlines(0)[0]
```

**Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/KivyPractice/practice.py", line 4, in <module>
    x = txt.readlines(0)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
cat
```

Comment: The first time you call `readlines()` it reads to the end of the file. The second time, there's nothing left to read. Assign the result to a variable and use that.

Comment: And if you just want the first line, don't read the whole file. Just call `readline()` to read one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
txt = open('path', 'rt')
lst = txt.readlines() 

print(lst[0])
```

Comment: This is what I am after! `readline()` works, but I do need to be able to grab a specific line, hence index it. Cheers!

Comment: This is great or horrible depending on what else you want to do. If you really just need the first line, you shouldn't read the whole thing.

Comment: I understand your concern, though I actually need every line, which is why I wanted to index it.

Answer (score 3):

`readlines` reads all of the lines. when you call `readlines` the second time, the file has already been read and there are 0 lines to go. `readline` reads one line. You could read that line into a variable first, and then print it.

```
txt_file = open('C:/Users/z/OneDrive/Desktop/New_Text_Doc.txt')
x = txt_file.readline()
print(x)
```

There are other ways to solve the problem. The best way depends on what you want to do next.

Comment: I see what is going on now, but I don't quite understand why it works that way. I understand that `readlines()` reads through all the lines, but when I call it again why wouldn't it start from the beginning of the opened .txt and read all the lines again? It's not like I am changing or updating the .txt. Sorry!

Comment: You can call `readlines` any time. Suppose you read the first 3 lines and then `readlines` the rest - you wouldn't want the rewind then. More generally, the underlying libraries keep a current position for a file. That's how its knows where the next reads and writes will go. That pointer shouldn't be reround to zero after a readline or readlines call. So, it would have to be at the start of a new read/readline/readlines call. But doing that each time would make the file unreadable. `readlines` is always "from the current position"/

Comment: I appreciate the more in depth explanation!

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

x = lines[0]
```

Comment: This would be an error because `x` isn't defined. And OP isn't asking about writing the file.

Comment: @tdelaney I assumed it was understood that x is defined by the OP earlier, but it seems I misunderstood the question, OP doesn't want to set the first line to `x`, rather read the first line of the file into the variable `x`.

Comment: If you change it to `x = lines[0]` it would work.

Comment: @tdelaney ah right, thanks, I forgot to fix my answer :-p.   Thanks for pointing it out.  I'm a bit surprised that none of the other answers is using a context manager to open the file! O_o